# How to track records in SQL and do some actions if it achieved a specific condition?

Tags: sql, database, t-sql

Let's say that I have **Equipment** table and **MaintenanceSchedule** table in SQL database.

So I need to update the value of the **Notification** (bit) field in the **Equipment** table to be true if  the **Date** field in the **MaintenanceSchedule** table approached.

So, how to track some data stored in the database and do some actions if a specific condition achieved ?

Comment: Sounds like a [trigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx)

Comment: No, I want to track the data stored in database by time. not when executing update statement -for example.

Comment: Maybe it is like a job, but how to implement this ?

Comment: Oh. I see. A job that runs every minute or hour or something to check against the `maintenanceschedule` table for records that have passed current or something and updated the `notification` bit field in your `equipment` table. Yes, that sounds like a job.

Comment: jobs, as I understand them, are scheduled stored procedures. So write an SP that does this (Which would be a simple `UPDATE` statement) and then schedule the job. If you are stuck with how to write the `UPDATE` sql  statement, or how to put that in a stored procedure, or how to schedule that SP, then perhaps a new SO question would be in order for that specific issue.

Comment: Maybe check out this: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3015/how-to-mark-an-item-as-expired-when-its-expirydate-value-is-in-the-past

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use a sql job to accomplish this. The problem is you want this process to be resilient in case of failure.

If you just set the flag after the Date field has approached, there are a couple potential bugs. For example, lets say the job doesn't run for some reason. If you run the job on the following day, can you be sure that the flag hasn't been properly set, then unset by the process which does the notification (or whatever processing is done). If you set it again, could it be duplicating work?

It would be best to create a MaintenanceHistory table which logs each time the Notification bit is set. Then you could build a stored procedure to run a job which checks if the Notification bit has been set for a particular Date, and if not, set the bit and log to the history table.

Then you could schedule this as a job which just executes this procedure and set to run at the desired frequency (hourly, daily, monthly, whatever). With this type of implementation, you can run the job as often as you like as it won't re-run for the same Date.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a [sql server job](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms191439.aspx) to check if the maintenance window aproaches and set the flag accordingly.

Comment: And how to implement the schedule for this job? every day ?

Comment: Depends on how often you have maintenance windows and their duration and also it depends if you want to set this flag upfront with a specified amount of time.